# Comparing variables in Java

Tags: java

I need one simple way to compare the following :

```
co1 = getvalue(c1) ; 
co2 = getvalue(c2) ; 
co3 = getvalue(c3) ; 
co4 = getvalue(c4) ; 
co5 = getvalue(c5) ; 
co6 = getvalue(c6) ;
```

The values that the variables co1, co2, c3 etc are being populated from a combobox. I don't want the user to choose the same item twice. I need to validate these. That is as long as the values do not equal each other, proceed ahead with the program..

Comment: I tried nested if statements but i want to avoid that

Comment: Why won't you store them in array or list?

Comment: It would have been easier to answer if we knew the types of `co1..co6` and `c1..c6`

Answer (score 4):

Whatever type `co1`, ..., `co6` has, I'm assuming it properly implements `equals` and `hashCode`.

One way is to use the Collections API as follows:

```
List<COType> coList = Arrays.asList(co1, co2, co3, co4, co5, co6);
if (new HashSet<COType>(coList).size() == coList.size()) {
    // no two elements are equal.
}
```

---

If you think that's not very readable, you could do it manually like this:

```
boolean areAnyTwoEqual(COType... co) {
    for (int i = 0; i < co.length-1; i++)
        for (int j = i+1; j < co.length; j++)
            if (co[i].equals(co[j]))
                return true;
    return false;
}
```

and call the function using

```
if (!areAnyTwoEqual(co1, co2, co3, co4, co5, co6)) {
    // no two elements are equal
}
```

Comment: Your `areTwoEqual` will only test if two consecutive elements are equal.

Comment: Right, but since the contract of `equals` says it must be transitive, that is equivalent of checking that they are all equal.

Comment: Just for completeness: When using `areTwoEqual(...)` the array should be sorted otherwise you'd need an inner loop to check the element at `i` against all that follow. Additionally, the method would return false if the first two elements are not equal, however, there might still be equal ones in the list, e.g. `{3, 2, 5, 3, 0 }` - Besides that, I'd say the `Set` approach is way better.

Comment: That would be true for testing if all are equal not if none are equal.

Comment: I agree that `areTwoEqual()` only works if the array is sorted. Otherwise it only returns `true` if **all** the values are the same.

Comment: @JohnB, perhaps the name was a bit misleading. I meant "are at least two equal". Change the name of the method.

Comment: The OP doesn't want to know if they are all equal. He just wants to know if *any two* are equal. Your `for` loop simply doesn't do this.

Comment: @aioobe The method would still not work correctly on unsorted arrays, see my edited comment.

Comment: Actually, the name seems to be correct (it returns true if all are equal and false otherwise) but the point of the exercise if to determine if any two are equal. Therefore `allAreEqual` is not the appropriate method. The `Set` solution is the better approach.

Comment: @Thomas the method is correct per its name (`allAreEqual`), it is just not applicable to the question at hand since what is needed is `anyAreEqual`.

Comment: @Thomas,JohnB, sorry guys. I obviously misunderstood the question and made a mess.

Answer (score 2):

Add them all to a `Set`, which cannot contain duplicate entries. Then, if `Set.size()` returns `6` you know all the values were distinct.

Example:

```
Set s = new HashSet();
s.add(c1);
...
s.add(c6);

if (s.size() == 6)
    // proceed
else
    // fail
```

Answer (score 2):

```
HashSet<?> set = new HashSet<?>();
for (? co : new ?[]{co1, co2, ...}){
      if (!set.add(co)){
          // duplicate element
      }
}
```

`Set.add` returns false if the element cannot be added because it already exists in the set. Use it to determine duplicate elements.

Comment: +1 Unlike looking at the size of the set, this approach will also tell you which values are in conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach is to store them in an array and compare them iteratively

```
boolean allDifferent = true;
Object[] values = {getValue(c1), getValue(c2), ...};

for (int i = 0; i < values.length - 1; ++i)
  for (int j = i+1; j < values.length; ++j)
    if (values[i].equals(values[j])
      allDifferent = false;
```

But I'd personally use a `Set` (also if it's a waste of allocations), or remove the item from the combo box when one is chosen (eg. if you select `item1` from cb2 then you remove the item from the others).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, we can iterate over `c1..c6`, this would do it:

```
Set<Type> temp = new HashSet<Type>();
for(Combobox box:boxes) {
  if (!temp.add(getValue(box)) {
    // duplicate entry - omit error message
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If those values come from `JComboBox` why not remove the selceted item of ComboBox1 from ComboBox2 and the selected item of ComboBox2 from ComboBox1?